# Restart Node.js application when uncaught exception occurs

Tags: javascript, node.js

How would I be able to restart my app when an exception occurs?

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {         
  // restart app here
});
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You could run the process as a fork of another process, so you can fork it if it dies. You would use the native [Cluster](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) module for this:

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
if (cluster.isMaster) {
  cluster.fork();

  cluster.on('exit', function(worker, code, signal) {
    cluster.fork();
  });
}

if (cluster.isWorker) {
  // put your code here
}
```

This code spawns one worker process, and if an error is thrown in the worker process, it will close, and the exit will respawn another worker process.

Comment: Is it possible to add a delay?

Comment: Wondering why ever use nodemon...

Answer (score 9):

You have a couple of options..

1. Restart the application using monitor like nodemon/forever

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {       
    console.log(err);
    //Send some notification about the error  
    process.exit(1);
});
```

start your application using

- [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon)

```
nodemon ./server.js
```

- [forever](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever)

```
forever server.js start
```

2. Restart using the [cluster](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html)

This method involves a cluster of process, where the master process restarts any child process if they killed

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
if (cluster.isMaster) {
   var i = 0;
   for (i; i< 4; i++){
     cluster.fork();
   }
   //if the worker dies, restart it.
   cluster.on('exit', function(worker){
      console.log('Worker ' + worker.id + ' died..');
      cluster.fork();
   });
}
else{
   var express = require('express');
   var app = express();

   .
   .
   app.use(app.router);
   app.listen(8000);

   process.on('uncaughtException', function(){
      console.log(err);
      //Send some notification about the error  
      process.exit(1);
  });
}
```

Comment: Please refer @hexacyanide

Comment: Why are you forking 4 times?

Answer (score 4):

checkout [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) and [forever](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever). I use nodemon for development and forever for production. Works like a charm. just start your app with `nodemon app.js`.