# Restart command in node.js?

Tags: node.js

I have a node.js server, i want to add it a command "restart" to restart the server WITHOUT closing tab and reopening it. Just like that:

```
[ME] restart................


[CONSOLE] close the server...............................


[CONSOLE] start the server....................
```

BUT WITHOUT CLOSING THE TAB

Is this possible? Im using [OgarProject.com](http://ogarproject.com) Nodejs. I really want to add this because is so annoying closing the tab and reopening it 'o' xD.

Comment: Do you mean Ctrl + C? That stops the server... Then you can restart it easily.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19336435/restart-node-js-application-when-uncaught-exception-occurs